# How Do I rename an XML Element Using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an XML element `<Third><Foo/></Third>` . I want to rename the element `<Third><Foo/></Third>` to `<Third><Foo01/></Third>` using Javascript. How do I do that?

Comment: You cannot rename it but you should be able to remove and re-add it

Comment: Because of the order that has to happen, I need to keep the element and its contents, and create a new blank element. The old element needs a new name.

Comment: Once an element has been created, you can only modify its attributes, attribute values, and/or element content. You cannot modify the element type.

Comment: What would you suggest if it can't be renamed? I would need to hold the element values, and create a new one named what I want then copy the values to a third element, then delete the first.

Comment: @user3179585 Yes, clone the first element's data into a new element, then delete the first element and insert the new one.

Comment: "*I have an XML element*" - what exactly? Do you work on a DOM? Or on an XML string? Or something else?